# How do I save to mongodb using mongoos and express?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I can't save a user to my mongodb, but I can get document. I get the following error each time I try to save a user. I get error from line 27 that's where the email starts from. I have tried other means too but the truth is that I am new to mongodb so I can't tell if the error is from the 
code or from the mongodb server. Please help.

> error: falior when reseiving data from peer

```
let User = require('../models/user.model')

const userController  = {
     //get all the users from   the  database
      getall :(req, res) => 
      {
        User.find()
        .then((users)=>res.json(users))
        .catch(err => res.status(400)
        .json('Error: ' + err));
        /*{field: filter},*/

      },

      //register  users //
      register :(req, res) =>{
        const {body} = req
        const {
            firstname,
            lastname,
            email,
            mobile,
            password
        } = body;

       //this is where the error start reporting for
            email = email.toLowerCase()
            User.find({ email : email}, (err, previousUser) => {
               if(err){
                   res.end({ success : false,  message : `Error ${err}`})
                }
                else
                {
                    if(previousUser.length > 0){
                        res.end({ success : false, message : 'Already registerd empty'
                        })
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        //using user model
                        const newUser  = new User();
                        //asign values to the user model
                        newUser.firstname = firstname
                        newUser.lastname = lastname
                        newUser.mobile = mobile
                        newUser.email = email
                        newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password)

                        //save 
                        newUser.save()
                        .then(()=>res.json('you have succesfuly registerd'))
                        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
                    }
               }
            });

        }

}

module.exports = userController
```

Comment: Please copy and paste exact error message you get. Your error message is propably something like "Failure when receiving data from the peer"

Answer (score 0):

I was so dumb the react component for the code above was not passing the required data for the Fields